# multi-threading with multiple CNN call weights

Tags: python, multithreading, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have dataset with 8 images for each class each entered into corresponding CNN (8 CNNs), all models are trained on tensorflow-gpu successfully. But when the weights of models are called in order to evaluate or test the model, it will be stuck in specific point, the gpu memory (2 GB) cannot be able to process them. I want to use multi-threading on cpu processor (8 GB) to process them. My calling models is as follow:

```
    model1 = load_model("model_1.model")
    lb1 = pickle.loads(open("label_1.pickle", "rb").read())
    .
    .
    .
    model8 = load_model("model_8.model")
    lb8 = pickle.loads(open("label_8.pickle", "rb").read())
```

How can I send each call into separate thread to be processed in parallel mode. Can anyone please help me, I will be thankful to him.
I hope it is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python multiprocessing module either using a pool or processes directly.

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process

def load_model(model):
    # stubbed for testing
    print("model:", model)

def handle_model(n):
    model = load_model(f"model_{n}.model")
    try:
        lb = pickle.loads(open(f"label_{n}.pickle", "rb").read())
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)

    # do work
    # ...


# pool style
pool = Pool(processes=8)
results = pool.map(handle_model, range(1,9))

# Process style
procs = []
for i in range(1,9):
 procs.append(Process(target=handle_model, args=(i,)))
 procs[-1].start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```